# Getting innerWidth of frame from another frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, frame

Say I have two frames `top_frame` and `bottom_frame`. Is it possible to get the innerWidth of `bottom_frame` from `top_frame` ?

I know we can use `$(window).innerWidth()` to get the inner width for current frame. But what about other frame.

I managed to do this in plain JavaScript using `top.frames["bottom_frame"].innerWidth`. But I am looking for a solution in jQuery.

Comment: I believe that top.frames["bottom_frame"].innerWidth is plain javascript expression

Comment: @Alexey Ogarkov Yes of course.. Silly me.. have edited it now

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).find("#bottom_frame").width()
```

`innerWidth()` cannot be used for `document` and `window` objects.

Comment: @Sachyn try without `contents()`

Comment: @Sachyn weird, sry, try parent() method.

Comment: @Sachyn 'null'? it means that its not `undefined`, culprit is innerWidth(), it selects the iframe tag, but innerWidth() is not applicable for window and document objecs. you should use `width()` instead, http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/

Comment: sorry.. but using `width()` also returns `null`

Comment: @Sachyn oh, ok, so something is wrong with selector, can you provide a jsfiddle? http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: i am using frames. How do I have multiple HTML files there ?

Comment: It again shows `null`. I want to access it from top_frame, I dont think I can use `#main_frame` as selector ?